# ReferenceError: Client is not defined Discord JS error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've just started working on a discord bot, but whenever I try to start it using node . in the cmd prompt, I get this error;

```
ReferenceError: Client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\imkav\Desktop\DiscordBot\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I've looked around and cant find anything specific enough to fix my issue. Here is my code;

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Client();

Client.login("TheToken");
```

As I said I just started today, so There isn't much here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Discord documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) says you should use `Discord.Client();`

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

Comment: Dear lord I'm an idiot, of course I forgot something so simple, thank you for your help friend, sometimes I forget where I left my brain.